# Check if difference between 2 dates is not more then 2 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this check in my PHP script done in mySQL where I select entry which meet conditions and I need to enhance this one:

```
outDate > ".sqltext(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data["inDate"])))."
```

`outDate` has to be later then `inDate`, but it should be later maximum by 2 days. The query now:

```
$sql = " SELECT id  
         FROM inputs_outputs
         WHERE objectId=".sqltext($data["objectId"])." 
         AND nfcTagId= ".sqltext($data["nfcTagId"])." 
         AND nfcText = ".sqltext($data["nfcText"])."
         AND inDate < ".sqltext(date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($data["outDate"])))."
         AND inDate !='0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
         AND outDate = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
         ORDER BY inDate DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I formatted the code, updated the tags and reworded the question for better readability and edited the title to reflect the question better.

Answer (score 1):

`datediff` returns the number of days between two dates, so you could use the following where clause to make sure that outDate is no more than 2 days greater than inDate

```
where outDate > inDate AND datediff(outDate,inDate) <= 2
```